# Suppose $p(x)$ Is a real polynomial, find $a$ and $b$ and factorize

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

having some troubles with this question:

Suppose $p(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + x + b$ is a real polynomial with $2 + i$ as a zero, find $a$ and $b$ and factorize $p(x)$ into a real linear and irriductable quadratic factors.

Any pointers of where to go from here would be a great help

Comment: Since the coefficients are real, the complex conjugate of any root is also a root. So that gets you a second root. Then recall Vieta's formulas. In particular, the one relating to the coefficient of the $x$ term.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of Algebra (in this context, polynomials with real coefficients have complex roots appear in conjugate), trivially $2-i$ is also a zero. And by Vieta's theorem, taking the root other than the conjugate pair (must be real) be $k$, one must get:
$$k(2-i)+(2+i)(2-i)+k(2+i)=1$$
$$4k+5=1$$
$$k=-1$$
Thus, we could answer the second question first:
$$P(x)=(x+1)(x-2+i)(x-2-i)$$
$$=(x+1)(x^2-4x+5)$$
And again by comparing the coefficient (or straightly Vieta's theorem), we could get
$$-a=4+k=3\Rightarrow a=-3$$
$$-b=5k=-5\Rightarrow b=5$$

Remarks:

Vieta's theorem of polynomials of degree $3$:

For the three roots of $P(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$, $i, j, k\in\mathbb C$, notice that the polynomials could be expressed in the form
$$P(x)=(x-i)(x-j)(x-k)$$
Expanding it,
$$P(x)=x^3+(-(i+j+k))x^2+(ij+ik+jk)x+(-ijk)$$
Comparing the coefficient, 
$$-a=i+j+k, b=ij+ik+jk, -c=ijk$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $2+i$ is a root, $2-i$ is also a root.

$$p(x)=(x-k)(x-2-i)(x-2+i)$$

$(x-2-i)(x-2+i)=(x-2)^2+1$.

comparing coefficients and obtain the answer.

---

\begin{align}
x^3+ax^2+x+b&=(x-k)(x^2-4x+5)\\
&=x^3-(k+4)x^2+(4k+5)x-5k
\end{align}

Therefore, $-k-4=a$, $4k+5=1$ and $-5k=b$

Comment: I'm having issues finding the values a and b. Could you please explain further on how to find them?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: if $$2+i$$ is a solution of $$p(x)=0$$ then $$x=2-i$$ is also a solution of $$p(x)=0$$